# Returning hundreds of errors when including SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3kxX.png)I am learning swift at the moment and recently tried to use SwiftyJSON to parse JSON data. However, following a tutorial, when I dragged the SwiftyJSON.swift file into my project window, it immediately shows 100+ errors in the SwiftyJSON file. Because of this, I am unable to use SwiftyJSON in my projects and can't gather data from the web.  I am using Xcode 8.2 and learning Swift 3.0.

Has anyone else had this problem, and have a solution to it?
Sorry if this is a really dumb question by the way.

Edit: Error Image Linked

Comment: Please share the error what you got

Comment: Update swiftyJson codebase to latest swift version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY, very easy fix, so don't worrry!

In your SwiftyJSON.swift file, at the very top, there is some weird WebResource text that should either be removed, or at the very least commented out.

Below is what your SwiftyJSON.swift file should look like:

[image]

As opposed to:

[image]

Hope this helps! Very simple mistake, but easy to miss because its at the top of the huge Permissions comment block!

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I removed those lines and still get the same problems. It seems that Xcode thinks that there is a problem with the actual code in the SwiftyJSON.swift file (errors like expected declaration etc.) - but I doubt this as I downloaded it from the offical GitHub source.

Comment: Try doing a clean and rebuild, cmd-shift-k to clean and cmb-b to build. Those errors are definitely coming from that line at the top. It's saying "expected declaration" everywhere because you had a faulty line right at the top so all the rest of the code below it was failing. Also, if your SwiftyJSON.swift file in the project directory? Are you working in Obj-C and trying to use this swift file?  Make sure to check all of your parens, make sure they all have an open and closed. I just downloaded the file myself and it's perfect so u must've messed with something at some point.

Comment: Just remove the SwiftyJSON file you're using from your project, and drag and drop a new one from where you downloaded/cloned it into your project

Comment: Thanks! I completely replaced the SwiftyJSON file in my project and it turns out that I was downloading the file from GitHub incorrectly, in a different format.